# Cakephp OR condition Implementation

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
class AbcController extends AppController {
public function foo{
$conditions = array();
$conditions['City.id']=1;
$conditions[array('OR'=>array(
                        'Subject.start_time1 BETWEEN ? AND ?'=>array($this->request->query['filters']['min_time'], $this->request->query['filters']['max_time']),
                        'Subject.end_time1 BETWEEN ? AND ?'=>array($this->request->query['filters']['min_time'], $this->request->query['filters']['max_time']),
                        'Subject.start_time2  BETWEEN ? AND ?'=>array($this->request->query['filters']['min_time'], $this->request->query['filters']['max_time']),
                        'Subject.end_time2  BETWEEN ? AND ?'=>array($this->request->query['filters']['min_time'], $this->request->query['filters']['max_time'])
                    ))];
$this->paginate = array('conditions' => $conditions);
try {
                    $off =  $this->paginate('Abc');
                } catch (NotFoundException $e) {
                    $requestUrl = $this->request->here();
                    $newUrl = preg_replace('/page:(\d+)/', 'page:1', $requestUrl);
                    $this->redirect($newUrl);
                }
}
```

Every thing work fine but implementation of OR condition give me error Illegal offset type in Controller APP\Controller\AbcController.php

Comment: please up-vote the answer also. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing OR condition in a wrong manner, just try this ---

```
    conditions += array('City.id'=>1);
$conditions += array('OR'=>array(
                        'Subject.start_time1 BETWEEN ? AND ?'=>array($this->request->query['filters']['min_time'], $this->request->query['filters']['max_time']),
                        'Subject.end_time1 BETWEEN ? AND ?'=>array($this->request->query['filters']['min_time'], $this->request->query['filters']['max_time']),
                        'Subject.start_time2  BETWEEN ? AND ?'=>array($this->request->query['filters']['min_time'], $this->request->query['filters']['max_time'),
                        'Subject.end_time2  BETWEEN ? AND ?'=>array($this->request->query['filters']['min_time'], $this->request->query['filters']['max_time'])
                    ));
```

Comment: I want to use $condtition as a variable, so cannot add together all conditions. Could you please correct the syntax for the given above @anant

Comment: Ok let me do that in my answer it self.

Comment: I edited it. Please check and if any error occur let me know.

Comment: Always welome. It's Great to hear that problem is solved and thanks for marking it.:):):)